# Why does SqlDataAdapter's fill not allow me to add a row with the same its own rows' value as appearance?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldataadapter

Why does SqlDataAdapter's Fill method not allow me to add a row with the same its own rows' value as appearance? I could not success to provide a row's value that appears at the same row with filled one in DataTable.
 [Check this out:](http://i.hizliresim.com/nAdRO1.png)

```
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SIPNO, SERINO, TARIH FROM SNOHAREKETLER WHERE Cast(TARIH as DATE) BETWEEN '2015/03/19' AND '2015/03/20' AND (TEZNO = 'T23' OR TEZNO = 'T31') AND CIKTI is null", c))
            {
                // 3
                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);

                t.Columns.Add("MyColumn", typeof(string));

                DataRow workRow;

                int iGetCount = t.Rows.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i <= iGetCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    workRow = t.NewRow();
                    workRow["MyColumn"] = i;
                    t.Rows.Add(workRow);
                }

                // 4
                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
            }
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message in your code?

Comment: You are ADDING rows to the existing rows collection. Do you want to UPDATE the existing rows and setting the new column of each EXISTING row to the index of the row? Probably your code fails because when adding rows you need to provide values for every column that cannot be leaved to NULL value

Comment: Soner, nothing has thrown out.

Comment: Steve, There is no any failure. The code works fine. Please check the screen out, It can give ideas that I added in my post. DataGridView is not in a mode that allow user can do somethings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of my issue. I searched and consulted someone. My issue was trying to add a NewRow and this causes the issue.

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
a.Fill(t);

DataColumn newCol = new DataColumn("NewColumn", typeof(string));
newCol.AllowDBNull = true;
t.Columns.Add(newCol);
foreach (DataRow row in t.Rows)
{
     row["NewColumn"] = "With String";
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```